# Как получить первый встречающийся символ в строке?

Tags: c++, qt, строки

Здравствуйте. Как получить `первый` встречающийся символ в `QString`?
Я попробовал использовать метод `indexOf()`, но он возвращает `последний` встречающийся элемент.
Пример:

```
int first_index = url.toString().indexOf("=");
int second_index = url.toString().indexOf("&");
QString token = url.toString().mid(first_index+1, second_index);
```

Результат:

```
"e36564a096f613073d8741c47cfafb626033259877aed4d129a3e01ec3b0a754a990e8025770e51f37f7&expires_in=86400&user_id=426163101"
```

Как видите, он выводит строку до конца строки. Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример из документации:

```
QString x = "Nine pineapples";
QString y = x.mid(5, 4);            // y == "pine"
QString z = x.mid(5);               // z == "pineapples"
```

Второй аргумент - количество символов

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам!